# Unresolved reference on views using MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm a beginner in MVVM and I tried [this](https://resocoder.com/2018/09/07/mvvm-on-android-crash-course-kotlin-android-architecture-components/) tutorial. Created a lot of files and pasted the codes but my views aren't recognized. My QuotesActivity.kt file:

```
package my.mvvm.ui.quotes

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import my.mvvm.R
import my.mvvm.data.Quote
import my.mvvm.utilities.InjectorUtils

class QuotesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes)
        initializeUi()
    }

    private fun initializeUi() {
        // Get the QuotesViewModelFactory with all of it's dependencies constructed
        val factory = InjectorUtils.provideQuotesViewModelFactory()
        // Use ViewModelProviders class to create / get already created QuotesViewModel
        // for this view (activity)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(QuotesViewModel::class.java)

        // Observing LiveData from the QuotesViewModel which in turn observes
        // LiveData from the repository, which observes LiveData from the DAO ☺
        viewModel.getQuotes().observe(this, Observer { quotes ->
            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            quotes.forEach { quote ->
                stringBuilder.append("$quote\n\n")
            }
            textView_quotes.text = stringBuilder.toString()
        })

        // When button is clicked, instantiate a Quote and add it to DB through the ViewModel
        button_add_quote.setOnClickListener {
            val quote = Quote(editText_quote.text.toString(), editText_author.text.toString())
            viewModel.addQuote(quote)
            editText_quote.setText("")
            binding.editText_author.setText("")
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas why this happens? Already tried with two examples and I had the same issue. Thanks.

Edit:

```
import com.resocoder.mvvmbasicstut.data.Quote
import com.resocoder.mvvmbasicstut.databinding.ActivityQuotesBinding
import com.resocoder.mvvmbasicstut.utilities.InjectorUtils
//import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_quotes.*

class QuotesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityQuotesBinding



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityQuotesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
```

[image: Errors]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.quotes.QuotesActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_quotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.55"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        tools:text="I like pineapples. - Thomas Jefferson"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_quote"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="Quote"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_quotes"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_author"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="Author"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_quote"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_quote"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="?colorAccent"
        android:text="Add Quote"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_author"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText_quote"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText_quote"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I just edit project from github. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ResoCoder/mvvm-android-architecture-crash-course)

Comment: What reference exactly cannot be resolved? I see `binding`, implying viewbinding and `editText_quote` impying synthetics. Which one are you trying to use? `editText_quote` should be imported if enabled, `binding` should be created by you if enabled. `binding` is not defined, however.

Comment: I just downloaded its GitHub project (didn't notice before). It works well when using kotlin extensions plugin but I can't get it working with viewBinding for some reason. Look at my edited question. I don't want to be outdated with synthetic properties.

Comment: I see you have correct the expected imports; what exactly does not work?

Comment: Please look at screenshot. Unresolved reference.

Comment: Could you add your xml as well? Does fi. `binding.editText_quote` resolve?

Comment: Just added it to question. No, no views resolve.

Comment: A long shot, because I genuinely don't know: can it be because in your gradle file, `buildFeatures { dataBinding = true }` instead of `buildFeatures { viewBinding = true }`?

Comment: I use `buildFeatures { viewBinding = true }`. Are you familiar with MVVM? Do you use synthethic properties only? Anyways. Thanks for your help and efforts.

Comment: Go to File->Invalidate caches/restart

Comment: This has no relation to MVVM whatsoever, just is purely a view binding problem. Does binding have any fields; if you type `binding.`, are there any views listed? Perhaps `editText_quote` is translated to camel case `binding.editTextQuote`?

Comment: OMG. I was using `editText_quote` instead of `editTextQuote`. Forgot that it works this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 'Look at my edited question' in Laba Diena's 'Edit:' above of wanting to use View Binding instead of the Kotlin Android Extension with synthetic view bindings is fairly straight forward. There are only two project files that need changing, namely:

```
(1) 'build.gradle (Module)' and
(2) 'QuotesActivity.kt'

Note: The other project files from the MVVM tutorial can be used 'as is'.  
Just make sure that your own 'package name' is at the top of these files.
```

**Project Structure**:

[image: build.gradle plugins section]

---

### (1) build.gradle file:

a) Make this change to the 'plugins' section:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'    // Delete this line
}
```

b) Add this entry to the 'android' section:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

c) Add this lifecycle option to the 'dependencies' section:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

---

### (2) QuotesActivity.kt:

Make the necessary changes to the 'QuotesActivity.kt' file as outlined below:

[image: QuotesActivity.kt package & import section]
[image: QuotesActivity.kt class code section]

**IMPORTANT**: When this project is built, it generates a Java file with the necessary databindings for this activity file. It will contain **new names** that you will have to use with the 'binding' variable in place of the xml attribute names that were previously used. For example, 'button_add_quote' now becomes 'buttonAddQuote', etc. See excerpt below showing the other **new names**:

```
public final Button buttonAddQuote;      // button_add_quote
public final EditText editTextAuthor;    // editText_author
public final EditText editTextQuote;     // editText_quote
public final TextView textViewQuotes;    // textView_quotes
```

All these **new names** can be found in a file called 'ActivityQuotesBinding.java' which is located in the project folder:

'app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out/**com**/**example**/**mvvmcrashcourse**/databinding/'

In the above path, the package name used for this particular project is "**com.example.mvvmcrashcourse**". Substitute it with your package name.

---

Finally, this solution works and was tested with Android Studio Bumblebee. If you have problems with build errors, try the following menu options:

- Build -> Clean Project
- Build -> Rebuild  Project
- File -> Invalidate Caches